# Having problems with npm install build in quip

Tags: quip, liveapps

Once the Quip app is created and npm start compiles and the app is error free when I build the app with npm install build it does not build with error

"found 12 vulnerabilities (6 low, 2 moderate, 3 high, 1 critical) in 9845 scanned packages
  12 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details."

I am using node node 12.14.1 and npm 6.13.4

It was running fine on ubuntu linux 18.04 but stopped working after an update. Tried installing under windows 10 having the same problem. Kindly advice. Unable to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The command to build your app should be `npm run build`, `npm install build` would install a package called `build` from the npm registry, which is not what you intend to do.